# Creating ArcMap point feature with ascending number symbol within it?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, point, symbology

I made a map of a planned route, at each of the routes stops (total of 15) I would like to have a point feature with a number in the middle of the point (think pool ball with the number on the ball) to represent that particular route stop.

Does anyone know the most straight forward/simple way I can go about making something like this?

Comment: Pick big circle filled symbol. Label your points making sure location is top of the point

Answer (score 6):

Open the layer properties for your route.

Go to the label tab.

Click on 'Symbol'.

Scroll down through all the available styles until you reach the following:

[image]

Select any of the symbols with the number inside the polygon and edit them to suit your needs by selecting the symbol and clicking 'Edit Symbol...'

Comment: you're welcome.  could you accept the answer?  that way it won't show up as unanswered anymore.